# What's the significance of Schloimele looking unrecognizable at the end of Isaac Bashevis Singer's "Schloimele"?

Tags: short-stories, yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer

At the end of "Schloimele" by Isaac Bashevis Singer, the titular character is described as being almost unrecognizable at the end of the story:

> He wore a straw hat, a pink shirt, and a bow tie. Although I had met him two days before, I barely recognized him. This was not the Schloimele I knew but an elderly man, grey-haired, bent, with a yellow complexion, a wrinkled double chin, and sad eyes under bushy brows. For a while he stared at me in bewilderment as if he, too, could not believe what he saw. Then he started, a smile lit up his face, and in a split second he became Schloimele again.
> <sub>(translated by Alma Singer and Elaine Gottlieb)</sub>

What's the significance of this scene? Why is he described as looking so different from the jolly man our narrator knows, and then a smile having him "...became Schloimele again"? What's going on here in this scene?